# Create distance matrix using a custom similarity function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, distance

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
        'age':[20, 21,18,54,23,11, 19, 18,12],
       'experience':[5,4,3,8,2,11,2,8,6]},columns=['id','age','experience'])

   id  age experience
0   1   20  5
1   1   21  4
2   1   18  3
3   2   54  8
4   2   23  2
5   2   11  11
6   3   19  2
7   3   18  8
8   3   12  6
```

I am using a custom distance function called dtw_path which calculates distance between tuples. I am not going into how exactly that function calculates distance as its a complex procedure, but it just outputs a scalar distance value between the tuples.

The tuple are being formed in the following fashion:

```
data['age_exp'] = data[['age', 'experience']].apply(tuple, axis=1)

    id  age experience  age_exp
0   1   20   5          (20, 5)
1   1   21   4          (21, 4)
2   1   18   3          (18, 3)
3   2   54   8          (54, 8)
4   2   23   2          (23, 2)
5   2   11   11         (11, 11)
6   3   19   2          (19, 2)
7   3   18   8          (18, 8)
8   3   12   6          (12, 6)
```

So for the above data frame if i need to calculate distance between id 1 and id 2, I would calculate the distance as follows:

```
data1 = data[data['id']==1]
data1 = np.array(data1['age_exp'].tolist())
data1

array([[20,  5],
       [21,  4],
       [18,  3]])

data2 = data[data['id']==2]
data2 = np.array(data2['age_exp'].tolist())
data2

array([[54,  8],
       [23,  2],
       [11, 11]])

dtw_path(data1,data2)[1]

1.5
```

What i need help is how to loop through the data frame and create a distance matrix for id column i.e. something like this

```
     1    2     3
1    0    1.5   2          
2    1.5  0     2.3
3    2    2.3   0
```

Comment: what exactly is `dtw_path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear in your question what `dtw_path` is. I used here [`tslearn.metrics.dtw_path`](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/metrics/tslearn.metrics.dtw_path.html), which gives me different results. Yet, the rationale should be the same.

Let's first reshape a bit the original dataframe:

```
data2 = (data.groupby('id')
             .apply(lambda x: np.array(list(zip(x['age'], x['experience']))))
        ).to_frame()
```

```
                               0
id                              
1    [[20, 5], [21, 4], [18, 3]]
2   [[54, 8], [23, 2], [11, 11]]
3    [[19, 2], [18, 8], [12, 6]]
```

NB. It requires to be two-dimensional (DataFrame) for the next step, thus the `.to_frame()`

Then, apply your `dtw_path` function using [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) that can take an arbitrary distance function using the parameter `metric` and keep only the second element of the output. Finally, reshape the output as a square matrix using [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html):

```
squareform(pdist(data2, metric=lambda x,y: dtw_path(x[0], y[0])[1]))
```

output:

```
array([[ 0.        , 35.86084215,  8.94427191],
       [35.86084215,  0.        , 36.7151195 ],
       [ 8.94427191, 36.7151195 ,  0.        ]])
```